Identifying misclassified samples in randomForest
I am performing a random forest analysis in RStudio and I can extract the confusion matrix using the code below. I can see how many samples are incorrectly classified, but what code can I use to identify which specific samples are being misclassified?
library(randomForest)
library(rfPermute)

rfmetrics <- randomForest(x, y, ntree=ntree, importance=T)
print(rfmetrics)

Call:
 randomForest(x = x, y = y, ntree = ntree, importance = T) 
               Type of random forest: classification
                     Number of trees: 1999
No. of variables tried at each split: 25

        OOB estimate of  error rate: 56.88%
Confusion matrix:
  1  2  3 4 class.error
1 8  7  7 4   0.6923077
2 4 19  2 4   0.3448276
3 3  3 15 6   0.4444444
4 3  9 10 5   0.8148148


It's easier to help you if you include a simple reproducible example with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Explicitly list the non-base R packages you have loaded.

We can better help you if you share a minimal reproducible example. Anyway, this code could be useful:
library(dplyr)
data.frame(y, y_hat = myrf$predicted) %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  filter(y != y_hat)

where y is your observed response vector, y_hat is the predicted value based on your estimation, id inside mutate is a new column indicating the position of the i-th observation and y != y_hat filters only observations misclassified. You can use id to locate those values.

This is the line that ended up giving me a list of each samples classification within the RF model.
rfmetrics$predicted 

Thanks for your help!
